# Can't create new maven web project in netbean

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I try to create a new project I got error like this. I can create normal maven project.
I also try proxy and mirror config in the setting.xml file and still no luck.
I use netbean 12 with jdk 8 and maven 3.6.3

```
The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:3.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available
```

````
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2 or one of
 its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:jar:3.1.2 has not been 
downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]```
````

Comment: It sounds like the repo was down briefly - I'm able to access it now.  I'd try it again and if it's still not working then check your network connections.  Do you have a firewall?

Comment: I'm already turn off firewall. @stdunbar

Comment: Nevermind,I found the solution.Just delete the "--offline" from Tools/options/java/maven/global execution options and Boom it's download require jar automatically.